# How to insert Robots.txt file

Tags: google-analytics, robots.txt

I made a website with single page but I want to know that where to insert robots.txt file and also where to insert google anaytics code.

Comment: Please make your question more specific. What have you tried so far? Where are you having problems?

Comment: I've not worked with Google Analytics, but I suspect there are some good tutorials available. A little quality time with your favorite search engine would probably prove fruitful.

Answer (score 0):

You place the robots.txt file in the root directory of the web site. So if your site is at www.example.com, you create www.example.com/robots.txt.

There is *one* robots.txt file for the entire site. All crawler directives for the entire site go in that one file.

See [Google's Robots.txt page](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt) for more information.